# Generating an executable .jar with dependencies (external jars) in Eclipse

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

So, he's the deal: I've browsed around and read a lot about Maven. Messed around with it a little but its use seemed overly complicated regarding to a task Eclipse should have no problem ion doing by itself: How do I generate an executable .jar file that have A LOT of external .jar dependencies without resorting to Maven or Ant?

If it can't be done with Eclipse, even some command-line based method will do.

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you want:

http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

It supports Ant, Maven, and command-line usage.

Quickstart at:
http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=quickstart