# Jar file created with Eclipse: Could not find the main class: UI.MainWindow. Program will exit

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, program-entry-point, classnotfoundexception

I have a Java application developed with Eclipse. I have tried to export it as a .jar file, to run it indipendently, but if I try to run it with the command

> java -jar application.jar

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccesController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$%AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Could not find the main class: UI.MainWindow. Program will exit

Currently, the main class is MainWindow.class. It contains a **public static void main(String[] args)** method.
I have checked the manifest.mf file and it seems correct:

> ```
>   Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Main-Class: UI.MainWindow
> ```

I am using a *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers version: Helios Release*, on a 64-bit Windows 2008 system.

What could I do?
How could I solve this?
What's the sense of the org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset error?

Thanks

Comment: JFree chart isn't on your classpath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually a case that occurs when one or more of your required dependency jar files are not included on your class path, and from the `MANIFEST` snippet you included, it seems this is your problem.

On another note, you might wanna use the Export `Runnable Jar` feature, this guarantees that your exported jar will work, given that your `Runtime Configuration` used as template for exporting this jar is proper.

Comment: Thanks: I did not know about the "Export as Runnable JAR file" on Eclipse. I've tried it, fixed some configuration details, and everything works fne! Many ultra-super-thanks from Italy to Jordan! ^_^

Comment: Super-awesome-welcome from Jordan to Italy, don't mention it @DavideChicco.it ;)
Eclipse is a great IDE in my opinion (I also like netBeans for some of it's features such as the Profiling feature). So, I encourage you to explore more of it!

Answer (score 2):

2 things you could do is

1. Launch the java application with dependency jar in class path as below.
   `java -cp jfreechart-1.x.x.jar -jar application.jar`
2. > Add Classpath option with in your MANIFEST.MF as below
   >   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   >   Main-Class: UI.MainWindow 
   >   Class-Path: < PATH to the jfreechart-1.x.x.jar >

Comment: The (1) option got the same error as before. The (2) option give a slightly changed error: now the console says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: UI/MainWindow`, and the rest is the same. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just explore(open) the jar file whether it has really the mentioned class in it.

Comment: with in application.jar Under "UI" folder MainWindow.class file should be present.

Answer (score 0):

It means that in your code main() method - `org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset` is not found

Possible reason is org.jfree  library jar is not present in your classpath

Comment: I'll check now this library, but anyway my main class in NOT in the jfree package, it is in my MainWindow class...

Comment: yes , your main class is trying to access a Class `XYDataset` which is part of JFree chart library, which its unable to locate because its not available in classpath

Comment: I've repeated the export operation, by adding the \libraries\ folder this time. But the problem remains... :-(

Comment: look for the ways to include .jar files in classpath , when running an executable jar file for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021800/generating-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-external-jars-in-eclipse) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817651/bundling-jar-dependencies-with-executable-jar-ber-jar-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

1.You can try to put library into jdk class path
2.Then export jar and run

```
lib path will be
$JDK_HOME\jre\lib\ext
$JDK_HOME is your jdk installation root path
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar to this with the Google Web Toolkit sample web app creation.  This was erroring becuase the Java compiler was set to 1.6 and GWT v2.6 requires jdk 1.7 + .  I switched the jdk and version.  The GWT was able to compile.